# Rails / Multi-Tenancy: Conditional default scope based on a different model's db value / global setting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-tenant, scopes

I've got a Rails application that is multi-tenant. Every model has an account_id, belongs to an account, and has a default scope to a current account id:

```
class Derp < ApplicationRecord
  default_scope { where(account_id: Account.current_id) }
  belongs_to :account
end
```

This works well and I've used this pattern in production in other apps (I understand that default scopes are frowned upon, but this is an accepted pattern. See: https://leanpub.com/multi-tenancy-rails).

Now here's the kicker - I have one client (and potentially more down the line, who knows), who wants to run the software on their own server. To solve this, I simply made a Server model with a type attribute:

```
class Server < ApplicationRecord
  enum server_type: { multitenant: 0, standalone: 1 }
end
```

Now on my multi-tenant server instance, I simply make one Server record and set the server_type to 0, and on my standalone instance I set it to 1. Then I've got some helper methods in my application controller to help with this, namely:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  around_action :scope_current_account

  ...

  def server
    @server ||= Server.first
  end

  def current_account
    if server.standalone?
      @current_account ||= Account.first
    elsif server.first.multitenant?
      @current_account ||= Account.find_by_subdomain(subdomain) if subdomain
    end
  end

  def scope_current_account
    Account.current_id = current_account.id
    yield
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    redirect_to not_found_path
  ensure
    Account.current_id = nil 
  end
end
```

This works, but I've got large record sets that I'm querying on this particular standalone client (70,000 records). I've got an index on the account_id, but it took my main customers table from 100ms to 400ms on my development machine.

Then I realized: standalone servers really don't need to concern themselves with the account id at all, especially if it is going to affect performance.

So really all I've got to do is make this line conditional:

```
default_scope { where(account_id: Account.current_id) }
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
class Derp < ApplicationRecord
  if Server.first.multitenant?
    default_scope { where(account_id: Account.current_id) }
  end
end
```

But obviously that syntax wrong. I've seen some other examples on Stack Overflow for conditional scopes, but none seem to work with a conditional statement based on a completely separate model. Is there a way to accomplish something like that in Ruby?

EDIT: Kicker here that I just realized is that this will only solve the speed issue for the one standalone server, and all the multi-tenant accounts will still have to deal with querying with the account_id. Maybe I should focus on that instead...

Comment: Not necessarily  the best option but you could have perfectly passed a Proc to default_scope and add a "return unless Server.first.multitenant?" in it before the where call.
You can also inject the default_scope using an initializer if it is server dependent.
Or you can use a concern as you did, many options :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid using `default_scope` as I've been bitten by it in the past. In particular, I've had places in an application where I want to *definitely* have it scoped, and other places where I don't. The places where I want the scoping typically end up being controllers / background jobs and the places where I don't want / need it end up being the tests.

So with that in mind, I would opt for an explicit method in the controller, rather than an implicit scoping in the model:

Whereas you have:

```
class Derp < ApplicationRecord
  if Server.first.multitenant?
    default_scope { where(account_id: Account.current_id) }
  end
end
```

I would have a method in the controller called something like `account_derps`:

```
def account_derps
  Derp.for_account(current_account)
end
```

Then wherever I wanted to load just the derps for the given account I would use `account_derps`. I would then be free to use `Derp` to do an unscoped find if I ever needed to do that.

Best part about this method is you could chuck your `Server.first.multitenant?` logic here too.

---

You mention another problem here:

> This works, but I've got large record sets that I'm querying on this particular standalone client (70,000 records). I've got an index on the account_id, but it took my main customers table from 100ms to 400ms on my development machine.

I think this is most likely due to a missing index. But I don't see the table schema here or the query so I don't know for certain. It could be that you're doing a where query on `account_id` and some other field, but you've only added the index to the `account_id`. If you're using PostgreSQL, then an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` before the query will point you in the right direction. If you're not sure how to decipher its results (and sometimes they can be tricky to) then I would recommend using the wonderful [pev](http://tatiyants.com/pev/) (Postgres EXPLAIN Visualizer) which will point you at the slowest parts of your query in a graphical format.

---

Lastly, thanks for taking the time to read my book and to ask such a detailed question about a related topic on SO :)

Comment: Hey now! This is awesome. Thanks so much Ryan!

I started my Rails journey with MySQL and unfortunately never got around to switching over to using PostreSQL in subsequent projects. MySQL does have an explain feature. This visualizer looks awesome though.

I've got an index on all the fields individually, but I wonder if I need multiple column indexes? I'll post back after I look at the query in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

First, abstract the account scoping stuff that any account scoped model will have to an abstract base class that inherits from ApplicationRecord:

```
class AccountScopedRecord < ApplicationRecord
  self.abstract_class = true

  default_scope { where(account_id: Account.current_id) }

  belongs_to :account
end
```

Now any model can cleanly be account scoped like:

```
class Job < AccountScopedRecord
  ...
end
```

To solve the conditional, abstract that one step further into an ActiveRecord concern:

```
module AccountScoped
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    default_scope { where(account_id: Account.current_id) }
    belongs_to :account
  end
end
```

Then the AccountScopedRecord can do:

```
class AccountScopedRecord < ApplicationRecord
  self.abstract_class = true

  if Server.first.multitenant?
    send(:include, AccountScoped)
  end
end
```

Now standalone accounts can ignore any account related stuff:

```
# Don't need this callback on standalone anymore
around_action :scope_current_account, if: multitenant?

# Method gets simplified
def current_account
  @current_account ||= Account.find_by_subdomain(subdomain) if subdomain
end
```